# ASP.NET WebAPI - OAuth returning "error": "invalid_grant" after validation success

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I'm sending a request from my MVC application to my WebAPI where the OAuth2 is implemented. Request is something like:

```
Content-Type: application/application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json

grant_type:password
username:someusername
password:somepassword
```

Everything is ok, user is validated with a success, but the response that returns to my MVC is:

```
StatusCode:BadRequest
Content:invalid_grant
```

CORS is allowed:

```
app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

No idea what's wrong. It was working quite good before...

Answer (score 0):

> No idea what's wrong. It was working quite good before...

Your request payload is wrong. You indicated `application/application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as Content-Type which is invalid and unsupported by Web API. The reason you are getting `invalid_grant` error is because the Web API didn't understand this request and couldn't even read the `grant_type` parameter from it.

So you could fix your request:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json

grant_type=password&username=someusername&password=somepassword
```

Here we use a standard and correct Content-Type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and also the request body respects the content type that we indicated.

Alternatively you could have used JSON:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json

{
    "grant_type": "password",
    "username": "someusername",
    "password": "somepassword"
}
```

Comment: I made a mistake in the post (only). Im using application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: OK, then the only remaining thing for you is to fix your payload so that it respects the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type as shown in my answer: `grant_type=password&username=someusername&password=somepassword`

Comment: `POST /api/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:57742
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: c4358da6-4ac7-2fea-eb36-7d9964208cf6

grant_type=password&username=jacek%40example.com&password=%242a%2410%24bVkBdoNTxdh3jbMw4twyDeefj5iOT9PkOXp6hzxyEJiIhDTjfv0Om`

Comment: That's quite different from what you have shown in your question. This looks good. I couldn't have possibly guessed it :-) So make sure that your OAuth Issuer is configured to support the `password` grant type.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wanted to make it short :) Don't You have any idea what can be wrong in that situation ?

Comment: It looks like your OAuth issuer doesn't support the password grant type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134199/discussion-between-marox-and-darin-dimitrov).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that you have the "users" in "AspnetUsers" table.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in the connection string. I have given a wrong db name and it was returning error 400 "invalid_grant". Fixed Db name and now it is working like before.